# Factoring problem

Tags: factorization

Keep factoring and concatenating starting with 2 until we get a prime, i.e. 2 = 2 ; 22=2.11 ; 22211=7.19.167 ; 22211719167=..... and so on (the prime factors are arranged from smaller to larger and their multiplicities are also written). How far we can go with these?,because factoring is very hard. I've already posted this question at Math Stack Exchange,but it seemed that we got stuck at the 102 digit number 2221171916731111.....797133 and I believe this last number is divisible by 3 eight times! and it not divisible by any other primes less than 100000,and Mr Moravitz said that maybe with mathematica or other heavier duty software we can get more than 102 digits (further terms). Could you give me the next term(s) ? (thank you)

Comment: Hi ! Please, head to the help centre and read about how to ask a question that is on-topic or you can head to the chat room and ask there.

Comment: I would also suggest adding a link to the other related post you're referencing.

Answer (score 2):

This will generate your sequence:

```
new[n_] := 
 Module[{digs = Flatten@Map[IntegerDigits, ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[n], {2}]},
  n*10^Length@digs + FromDigits@digs];

Nest[new,2,6]

(*
{2, 22, 22211, 22211719167, 2221171916731111313195493, \
222117191673111131319549333123883568997108723797801, \
2221171916731111313195493331238835689971087237978019091387255896718259\
28623195474482364099822833797133}
*)
```

Factoring of large integers is, I'm sure your aware, time consuming... how far you can carry the above in reasonable time depends on your hardware.

Comment: that last number 22211719167....797133 is divisible by 3 eight times,do you have any other prime factors for this number?

Comment: @NanaJ: I did not decompose the result further. You can try `FactorInteger` on the quotient, but it's a big number, so it will take a long time...

Answer (score 0):

The number factored is 3^8.310156649895217.9409221658282404210038668541308726969.11600516856059799467241240276984327980814066661
I factored it online with my HPZ420 workstation with 16GB RAM in just over 17 minutes. 
I like your project, it was nice to help. 
Best regards, 
Harry.